# Cocos2d Android CCRenderTexture example

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-android

```
CCSprite texture1 = CCSprite.sprite("menu_background.png");
CCRenderTexture layerRenderTexture = CCRenderTexture.renderTexture(width, height);
layerRenderTexture.begin();
texture1.visit(CCDirector.gl);
layerRenderTexture.end();
this.addChild(layerRenderTexture);
```

I haven't seen any CCRenderTexture example on Internet. When I try to use it as above, I expected to see a nice background. Instead I see black :)

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

> I haven't seen any CCRenderTexture example on Internet.

I think you may have been looking on the wrong Internet? :)

Check out [my article](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/12/how-to-use-ccrendertexture-motion-blur-screenshots-drawing-sketches/) and [Ray's article](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3857/how-to-create-dynamic-textures-with-ccrendertexture). Both come out on top when you google for CCRenderTexture. They use cocos2d-iphone, but the same principles apply.

In your particular case I don't see you adding the layerRenderTexture as child to the scene or another node. That would explain why you're not getting any results.

Comment: Firstly thanks for your reply:)

I have developed and finished my iPhone project already. Now I am trying to implement it on Android. At the links you sent me, it is written about Cocos2d on Iphone not Android.
By the way, of course I have added layerRenderTexture as child to the layer. I know the principle is same as iPhone, but I can not implement this on Android.

Comment: Long shot, maybe you're experiencing this issue? http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-android-1/issues/detail?id=71

Comment: do you have any solution for that?

Comment: "I think you may have been looking on the wrong Internet?" :)


Did you find anything in the correct Internet? :)